# Problem with static variable in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller like this:

```
class StudentsController extends AppController {
  var $name = "Student";


  function addstudent() {
    //$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    //$this->Session->write('id', $id);
    static $count = 0;
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
      $students = $this->Session->read('Student');
      if(!$students) {
        $students = array();
      }
      $students[] = $this->data['Student']; /* data */
      $this->Session->write('Student', $students);
      $this->Session->write('student_count',$count);

      //$this->Session->write('Student',$this->data['Student']);
      //$this->Session->setFlash($this->Session->check('Student'));
      //print_r($this->data);
      //print_r($this -> Session -> read());
      //$this->Session->setFlash('student has been saved.');

      $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'students','action' => 'addstudent'));
    }
  }
}
```

After adding a student to an array the count is incrementing and I am writing to session variable student count. I have added 3 students and i am doing `echo $this->Session->read('student_count');` in view but getting `0` every time.

I asked this question just few minutes ago, but the solution was not clear to me. Please tell me what piece of code to be added in the controller to get the number of students added in the view.

Comment: I think your static $count = 0 should be "out" of the method else it'll be reinitialized everytime you add a student

Comment: @Louskan: Nope, the way `static` works is that it's initialized only once, its value retained for every subsequent call.

Comment: Maybe a mistake with copy/pasting, but you never increase the $count variable in your snippet.

Comment: In this case what is the point of using static. count($students) and your $count will be same . is it?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, a static variable will retain its value for multiple calls to `StudentsController::addstudent`, but will not retain its value for multiple requests to `/students/addstudent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never incrementing the value of `$count`, and the `static` designation does not cause the variable to retain its value in subsequent requests, as PHP has no application state. You can fudge application state by reading *and* writing to your session var, in the same way you are doing with your `Student` collection.

```
function addstudent()
{
    if (!$count = $this->Session->read('student_count')) {
        $count = 0;
    }

    /* other operations in your action */

    $count++;
    $this->Session->write('student_count', $count);

    /* remaining bits of your action */
}
```